# combine files that share a similar characters

Tags: text-processing, cat

I have a folder with hundreds of files. These files are score files for 26 environmental variables across 510 genotype files. For example in the examples below, *_s2.* is the second environmental variable, *_s3.* is the third envriornmental variable, etc.  *_9_* indicates that this is for the 9th genotype file.

```
lfmm_run2_9_s2.3.zscore
lfmm_run2_9_s24.3.zscore
lfmm_run2_9_s25.3.zscore
lfmm_run2_9_s26.3.zscore
lfmm_run2_9_s3.3.zscore
lfmm_run2_9_s4.3.zscore
lfmm_run2_9_s5.3.zscore
lfmm_run2_9_s6.3.zscore
lfmm_run2_9_s7.3.zscore
lfmm_run2_9_s8.3.zscore
lfmm_run2_9_s9.3.zscore
...
```

I want to combine the genotype files for each environmental variable.
what I am doing is

```
cat lfmm_run2_{1..510}_s1.3.zscore > env1
cat lfmm_run2_{1..510}_s2.3.zscore > env2
cat lfmm_run2_{1..510}_s3.3.zscore > env3
```

But it takes a lot of time to do this for all 26 environmental variable one by one. Is there any faster way of doing this all together by a single command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for` loop to run `cat` 26 times, one for each number from 1 to 26:

```
for i in {1..26} ; do
    cat lfmm_run2_{1..510}_s"$i".3.zscore > env"$i"
done
```

Comment: it actually did not work like your command. we need to put the variable in comma citation. this works for i in {1..3} ; do
    cat lfmm_run1_{1..682}_s"$i".5.zscore > annuus_cov"$i"_run1_K5
done

Comment: Added quotes to my answer too. (Quoting variables is almost always more correct.) Although, I don't really see why this would fail without the quotes, in this particular case... Anyway, glad to see you got your issue figured out!